# Using a generic clear textbox method on event

Tags: c#, validation, input, textbox

I've got a program with a lot of text boxes that I've got text in that I want to be cleared on _click and then reset to default if nothing is entered and the user clicks away.

The way I was going to do it is clearly inefficient, having to name the text box each time and I'd like to know how I could go about streamlining it.

this is what I've got at the minute, and I'd have to change the txtUserName for the text box field name each time

```
private void txtUserName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtUserName.Text = ""
    txtUserName.ForeColor = Color.Black;
}
```

is there a way I can do essentially

```
private void txtAnyTextBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string caller = //Get this textbox name
    this.ClearBoxes(caller)
}

void ClearBoxes(string Caller)
{
    Caller.txt.Text = "";
   //..... and so on
}
```

Comment: Have you interested in watermarked textbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can try this (though it's not generic but there is no need for generics in this case):

```
private void txtAnyTextBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
   if(tb != null) tb.Text = "";
}
```

And you can attach this method to all your textBoxes `Click event`.

```
textBox1.Click += txtAnyTextBox_Click;
textBox2.Click += txtAnyTextBox_Click;
```

I don't think this is gonna work:

```
void ClearBoxes(string Caller)
{
   Caller.txt.Text = "";
   //..... and so on
}
```

If you want to use `ClearBoxes` method you should pass it your `TextBox` element.But there is no need for this,you can directly clear your textBox as shown above code.

Also if you want to clear all TextBoxes in the same time,for example one button click you can use this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var tBox in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        tBox.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get name of textbox from sender of event:

```
private void txtAnyTextBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    string caller = textBox.Name;
    this.ClearBoxes(caller); // call your custom method
}
```

If you want to simply clear textbox text, then you don't need to get its name - you can use it's `Clear()` method:

```
private void txtAnyTextBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    textBox.Clear();
}
```

Also you can consider creation of custom textbox, which will have some default value and will resent itself to default when clicked:

```
public class CustomTextBox : TextBox
{
    public string DefaultText { get; set; }

    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClick(e);
        Text = DefaultText;
    }
}
```

Use custom textboxes instead of default textboxes, and provide `DefaultText` value for each custom textbox which should reset itself to something more meaningful than empty string (you can use Properties window for that).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sender` argument for that.

```
private void txtAnyTextBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textbox = sender as TextBox;
    this.ClearTextbox(textbox)
}

private void ClearTextbox(TextBox textbox)
{
    textbox.Text = "";
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be quite nasty - as you'd cause a page reload every time someone clicked in the text box.

A far simpler way would be to do it in javascript.

just add a function to clear the text box, and then maybe use a css selector to enable the function for every text box you want to use it in.

e.g.

```
<input type="text" class="clearme" />

$(".clearme").click(function() {
    $(this).val('');
});
```

this will do it all client side without causing any post backs.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using windows forms for this one.

Comment: Oh I see! Mu apologies, I thought it was a web forms app.